# Member defined more than once

Tags: c#

I am new to the whole get and set thing, but this seems pretty straightforward, don't I set something but just calling `this.Var = value`?

```
public LoginView LoginView1 { get; set; }

void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.LoginView1 = (LoginView)FindControls.FindControlRecursive(Page, "LoginView1"); 
    RadGrid RadGrid3 = (RadGrid)LoginView1.FindControl("RadGrid3");
    RadGrid RadGrid4 = (RadGrid)LoginView1.FindControl("RadGrid4");
    UpdatePanel UpdatePanel1 = (UpdatePanel)LoginView1.FindControl("UpdatePanel1");
    LoadData();
}
```

My error is saying that `LoginView1` is defined more than once. All I want to do is set the global variable on Page Load.

Comment: If you don't see another declaration of `LoginView1` in your source file, check the parent class.  Member names have to be unique within the full inherited scope.

Comment: Did you add a `LoginView` through the designer?  That defines it; if you then add a property that is also called `LoginView1`, you're going to get that error.

Comment: just change the property name to Loginview2

Comment: sidenote: you should start your local variable names with lowercase letters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have it on the page itself, which means it is in the `designer.cs` file too, which means there is indeed a `LoginView1` already defined, for the login view you are trying to get.

Call it something else.

Comment: You were right. Thanks! -- I can't accept your answer for another ten minutes.